# How to add multiple chats to chatmanager in smack?

Tags: java, facebook, chat, smack

From smack docs:
The chat manager keeps track of references to all current chats.
It will not hold any references in memory on its own so it is neccesary to keep a reference to the chat object itself.

How can I keep track of all chat objects ?

Answer (score 0):

You may  use Vector object as global variable.

private static Vector  vectorchatPool=new Vector ();